# Is YubiKey 4 broken on Windows 10 'Creators Update'? PIV Manager 1.4.2 can't load smart card

Tags: drivers, device-manager, windows-10-v1703, smartcard

If I open YubiKey Piv Manager (1.4.2) then insert my YubiKey 4, everything works great the first time. It recognizes the key and allows me to initialize it. However, if I remove the key and try to do it again, YubiKey PIV Manager (1.4.2) fails to recognize the key.

- YubiKey 4 -- PIV applet firmware 4.3.4
- YubiKey PIV Manager version 1.4.2
- Windows 10 Pro, Creators Update (Version: 1703)

  > systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
  > OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
  > OS Version:                10.0.15063 N/A Build 15063

I get the following message in the YubiKey PIV Manager UI:

[image: No YubiKey found]

yubico-piv-tool.exe returns the following:

```
> .\yubico-piv-tool.exe -astatus
Failed to connect to reader.
```

I can get YubiKey PIV Manager to recognize the key again if I follow these steps:

1. Leave the YubiKey 4 inserted
2. Leave YubiKey PIV Manager (1.4.2) open
3. Open up Windows [Device Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager)
4. Navigate to "Smart card readers"
5. Find the "Microsoft Usbccid Smartcard Reader (WUDF)" device that was added by Windows, and right click to "Uninstall device"
6. Remove the YubiKey 4
7. Reinsert the YubiKey 4
8. Voilà! YubiKey 4 is recognized and I can work with it

Another interesting thing is that after following the process described above, when you reinsert the YubiKey 4, ever so briefly you see a device appear under `"Smart card readers"` called `"YubiKey 4 OTP+U2F+CCID"`. This eventually disappears only to be replaced by `"Microsoft Usbccid Smartcard Reader (WUDF)"` again. It is seemingly present long enough for YubiKey PIV Manager (1.4.2) to get started interacting with the key.

yubico-piv-tool.exe also works after following the process above.

After I remove the key, it won't work again unless I repeat the steps above to uninstall the device before plugging it back in.

Comment: I have had no problems with any of my YubiKey 4 keys on any of my numerous 1703 Windows 10 machines

Comment: @Ramhound I tried on a Dell 5510 where I found the problem.  I retried on a Dell M3800.  I am yet to see a machine that doesn't have the problem described above.  Did you use Yubikeys with your machines prior to upgrading to Windows 10 with build 1703?

Comment: @Ramhound If you are talking about anything other than PIV functionality, YubiKeys work great for me too on Windows 10.  It's just PIV and the YubiKey not working as a recognized smart card when I plug it in. 
 I filed this bug today: https://github.com/Yubico/yubikey-piv-manager/issues/24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was determined to be a Microsoft bug.  See the GitHub issue I filed for more details:

*[YubiKey 4 issues with Windows 10 Creators Update (Version 1703) #24](https://github.com/Yubico/yubikey-piv-manager/issues/24)*

A workaround seems to be:

- Add `SeLoadDriverPrivilege` to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ ScDeviceEnum\RequiredPrivileges`
- Reboot

Or, run this one-liner in PowerShell as an administrator:

```
$v = (gp "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\ScDeviceEnum" RequiredPrivileges).RequiredPrivileges; if (-not ($v -contains "SeLoadDriverPrivilege")) { $v += "SeLoadDriverPrivilege"; sp "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\ScDeviceEnum" RequiredPrivileges $v }
```